# How to extract values from html table to Python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, html-parsing

I have the following html code structure but I don't know how to extract the values of text1 and text2 from `<td> <a href ="....."> text1 </a> text2 </td>`

```html
<tbody>
        <tr class="trBgGrey"><td nowrap="nowrap">1</td><td nowrap="nowrap">11</td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?horseno=S205">SWEET BEAN</a>(S205)</td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/jockeyprofile.asp?jockeycode=MOJ&amp;season=Current">J Moreira</a></td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/trainerprofile.asp?trainercode=FC&amp;season=Current">C Fownes</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap">121</td><td nowrap="nowrap">1034</td><td nowrap="nowrap">7</td><td nowrap="nowrap">-</td><td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><table width="80" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tr><td width="16" align="center">8</td><td width="16" align="center">8</td><td width="16" align="center">8</td><td width="16" align="center">3</td><td width="16" align="center">1</td></tr></table></td><td nowrap="nowrap">1.51.13</td><td nowrap="nowrap">5.3</td></tr>
</tr><tr class="trBgGrey"><td nowrap="nowrap">3</td><td nowrap="nowrap">2</td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?horseno=V311">CITY WINNER</a>(V311)</td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/jockeyprofile.asp?jockeycode=RN&amp;season=Current">N Rawiller</a></td><td class="tdAlignL font13 fontStyle" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/trainerprofile.asp?trainercode=TYS&amp;season=Current">Y S Tsui</a></td><td nowrap="nowrap">132</td><td nowrap="nowrap">978</td><td nowrap="nowrap">6</td><td nowrap="nowrap">1</td><td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><table width="80" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tr><td width="16" align="center">9</td><td width="16" align="center">9</td><td width="16" align="center">9</td><td width="16" align="center">10</td><td width="16" align="center">3</td></tr></table></td><td nowrap="nowrap">1.51.30</td><td nowrap="nowrap">22</td></tr>
        </tbody>
```

I tried my codes as follows but cannot get the text values

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

race_link = 'http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/English/Local/20171227/HV'
sauce1 = urllib.request.urlopen(race_link).read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(sauce1, 'html.parser')

for link in soup1.find_all('tr', {'class': 'trBgGrey'}):
    for ilink in link.find_all('td'):
        print(ilink.string)
```

But my results return to:

```html
1
11
None
J Moreira
C Fownes
121
1034
7
-
None
8
8
8
3
1
1.51.13
5.3
.....
```

My expected results are

```html
1
11
SWEET BEAN
(S205)
J Moreira
C Fownes
121
1034
7
-
None
8
8
8
3
1
1.51.13
5.3
......
```

I can get the values from the html structure as

```
<td>text1</td><td>text2</td>
```

But I don't know how to code to get the values from the html structure as

```
<td><a href="....">text1</a>text2</td>
```

How can I get the values from the second structure?

Comment: I mean, I would like to extract text1 and text2 from the following html structure:

Comment: You want the horse name and ID?

Comment: sorry that it is my first time to post a thread here and missed out something. I amended my thread. In fact, I want to know how get the values (text1 and text2) inside a html structure as follows: <td><a hre="......">text1</a>text2</td>

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: in fact, i need all values including the horse name and ID. But now that I can only get all other values except horse name and ID. I want to get those both as well. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Please add example of expected output.
2. the code you added is not giving the output you gave. for example, there is no <tr> and there is no class trBgGrey

Comment: Amended the example codes and my expected results. Hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
from bs4 import element

def print_strings(elemnt):
    for c in elemnt.children:
        if isinstance(c, element.Tag):
            print_strings(c)
        else:
            print (c, end=" ")

for link in soup1.find_all('tr', {'class': 'trBgGrey'}):
    for ilink in link.find_all('td'):
        print_strings(ilink)
        print()
```

[**Try It Online**](https://tio.run/##vZNRa9swEMff9SmEHmYbgt00HYMs9lgL2xgrg6XvRZNkW40sCelMCGOfPZPspbVJtsfqwWfd/076nX1nD9AavToePe2ZWOISE0I24DBT1PuSgLttPjtxINUGONZm76gtyWhJtdwUwCt0UZpop7P4RyUb/Q3XRsNyNZgtHJQgZ9kbilsn6pK0AHZdFPv9Pm93TyxnpitYK7XwonCUSd0UrXFe5NTbD8ObNuX2@uotqb7EXaCgVRod2WvxPBm2EwfrTC3VyDV6mOGivP/@9Q3t7HsvqDe6vOudExpI9UNyEVFfCxIcDXs3pfzrGjA/3V2kfBhD5qBnf/76f21xtbr5t/pukMLDVaENEUK1Mx3@6W@w7KxxgIUSXSA5898K2oOse7U1vUWIixpbJzU8egim8WlM1JCtEQ6rNqG/sdR49Obh2ygeKhzVuGSNpZfaA9VMpGxxujh/oE32EhbX/B6WPYtCeXEhFA/HaV4STDKEfACOYzerIB2ncYGTFjqVWxo62SUhOpIrqXcRfsjMa6n5I1UqTcAlC/wrGfomWePkNLrJ70nZ8pQd7TSZJ5O65jUNOdlcTLPj8Q8)

Comment: @how2code please accept the answer if it helped and solve your question